# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: laravel, slim, guzzle

I use Guzzle in my Laravel 7 project and XAMPP 7.4.5, I'm trying to make a GET to my local API localhost/events_platforma/view/users It works fine but when I'm trying to make a POST request to https://localhost/events_platforma/register it fails and gives out that cURL error and My API Are on SLIM.

I have added this file

```
curl.cainfo = curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

But still, give out an error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quick solution for localhost is to turn off the certificate verification using options in guzzle of `verify` as false.

A quick small example below

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://exmaple.org'
]);
$client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => false]);
```

If you are using [Http-client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#guzzle-options) provided by laravel you can add guzzle options like this,

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
    'verify' => false,
])->get('http://example.org/');
```

#### NOTE:

Though even guzzle suggests to not using it, but if you are testing your own apis it can work.

---

Though you can simple add your certificates as per request just by providing path.

> Mozilla provides a commonly used CA bundle which can be downloaded [here](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) (provided by the maintainer of cURL).

```
// Use a custom SSL certificate on disk.
$client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => '/path/to/cacert.pem']);
```

Read more about certificates from https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html .

Read more about verify from guzzle docs [verify](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#verify)

Comment: It's work like a champ, i use this one  ` $response = Http::withOptions([
    'verify' => false,
])->get('http://example.org/'); `

Comment: you can also download the mozilla cacertificates given in link above & provide the path to make it secure