# MAMP Pro SSL issue using Guzzle

Tags: mamp, guzzle, mamp-pro

I am having trouble using **Guzzle** within a local environment via **MAMP**.
The site is using SSL.

The error is as seen below:

```
Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem CApath: none (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I was developing on a Windows machine using **XAMPP**, and things were working without issue.  I was not developing using SSL at that time.  I have migrated to a Mac and since have began using MAMP.

Things works as expected when deployed to a true staging server that also uses SSL.

Comment: use `verify=>false` to remove certification issue for now, though it is unsecure and temporary solution

Comment: I guess there is no CA cert file found in the path, add one, refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65882711/9471283

Comment: These are both awesome suggestions, but my next question would be whether or not there is a common practice when using MAMP when dealing with this issue?  Is setting `verify=>false` common when working locally in this scenario?

Comment: normally you would need verify=>false when then api you are calling or using is on local environment, then it is ok, but if it is external api then that api should have proper certificates such that there is no such issue, have you tried to run that api using chrome does it show certificates when you run it on chrome?